# linux apache cron-job - check file first

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, cron

I'm retrieving an xml file from an offsite third-party server and copying it to my local server. Problem is, once in a while the offsite server is down for maintance and during this time I don't want the crontab command to overwrite my local file. Is there a way I can check to make sure the file exists first, before copying?

**Current crontab**

```
0 * * * * username wget -O /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml https://AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD:x@myaccount.wufoo.com/api/v3/reports/123456/entries.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

You could download to a different file and overwrite wufoo.xml only if wget's [exit code](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) is OK:

```
wget -O /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml.new https://url/entries.xml && 
mv /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml.new /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml
```

You can move this to a separate script for clarity and invoke that script from your crontab.

Edit: or try curl, which doesn't seem to truncate the output file by default: `curl -o /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml https://url/entries.xml`

Comment: Good answer.  If the server at the other end is not behaving properly, it might return a success status code, but a bogus file.  If you split the logic out into another script (as you suggest), you could perform further sanity checks: is the resulting file a sensible length (starting with 'not 0 bytes' and perhaps moving onto something more sophisticated like 'not more than N bytes different to the original'), is the new file's contents of the right format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should only download the file if it doesn't exist.

```
if [ ! -f /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml ]; then wget -O /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml https://AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD:x@myaccount.wufoo.com/api/v3/reports/123456/entries.xml; fi
```